# Strange behavior of Array count()

Tags: php, arrays

I have following Array

```
$arr = array(1 => 1, "1" => 50);
```

When I execute count() on it, it gives me strange answer: 1

```
echo count($arr);
```

Whereas an array `$arr` has two elements.

Why?

Comment: Do `var_dump($arr)` and see something interesting.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo, It's giving `array(1) { [1]=> int(50) }`

Comment: So, it's an answer to a question, why it's count is 1, right?

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo, "If multiple elements in the array declaration use the same key, only the last one will be used as all others are overwritten." I just read from php.net

Comment: Oh, man. Please, read [this](http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo, Yes. That's what I just told you. So Now I understood your above comment. Thanks

Comment: So how about to change actions order? :p I.e. first go to php.net and then, if question was not answered, ask SO :p

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo, Ok. So you downvoted? I realized and so flagged it to close :)

Comment: No, that wasn't me - because if I do so, I always leave a comment (and my answer to your question in my 1-st comment isn't a reason to downvote)

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo, So now How can I delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to Type Casting . Check Example #2 Type Casting and Overwriting example in [Arrays](http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) .

> If multiple elements in the array declaration use the same key, only the last one will be used as all others are overwritten .

```
$arr = array(1 => 10, "1" => 20);
var_dump( $arr );
```

Displays :

```
array (size=1)
  1 => int 20
```

And so :

```
echo count( $arr );
```

Displays :

```
1
```

Which is correct .

Answer (score 1):

If multiple elements in the array declaration use the same key, only the last one will be used as all others are overwritten.As all the keys in the below example are cast to 1, the value will be overwritten on every new element.

Sample Code:

```
$array = array(
    1    => "a",
    "1"  => "b"

);
var_dump($array);
echo count($array);
```

Sample output:

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
}
1
```

For details have a look here:http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

if you change the "1" to "2" it will count 2. The problem is the fact that you choose the first element in the array to be 1 then you choose it to be 50, so in the final, the array will have one element, which is 50.

See it [here](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn%24arr%20=%20array%281%20=%3E%201,%20%221%22%20=%3E%2050%29;%5Cnecho%20count%28%24arr%29;%5Cnecho%20%22%2526nbsp;%20As%20you%20see,%20it%20is%20not%20working!%20%3Cbr%20/%3E%22;%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22%20Now%20try%20it%20like%20so%20%3Cbr%20/%3E%22;%5Cn%24arr1%20=%20array%281%20=%3E%201,%20%222%22%20=%3E%2050%29;%5Cnecho%20count%28%24arr1%29;%5Cn?%3E)!